# JSP dropdownlist onChange

Tags: jsp, onchange, html-select

Can i use a .jsp file as a parameter for onChange in a dropdownlist? Like this :

```
<td><select name="transporter" onchange="debusTransporter.jsp">
```

Comment: JSP executed at the server side that gets transformed into Java the first time is processed by the servlet container. onchange is event that interpreted by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is **No.**

### Explanation

[onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onchange)

The onchange property sets and returns the **event handler** for the change event.

[The term event handler may refer to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Event_handlers):

- **any function or object registered to be notified of events,**
- or, more specifically, to the mechanism of registering event listeners via on... attributes or properties in HTML and other web APIs, such as `<button onclick="alert(this)">` or `window.onload = function() { /* ... */ }`.

### See also

- [w3.org ONCHANGE-SELECT](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0102/0102-ONCHANGE-SELECT.html)
- [reference.sitepoint.com onchange](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onchange)